# wordpress woocommerce single product page customisation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce providing predefined templates like single product page.
In my theme the single product page look and layout is different .
how to override single product page to show our own design view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce operates a hierarchy template system, so it will check your theme for a template file first, and if one isn't present it will fallback to it's own.

Create a folder within your theme called `woocommerce`.  This houses your template overrides.  Create a file here called `single-product.php`.

This file will override the existing one.  You can find the existing file [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.1.0/templates/single-product.php), assuming you're running version `2.1.0`.

WooCommerce has some [great documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) on how to tweak your template files.

Comment: Hi i created folder as you said, i created a single-product.php page and i remove all the code, and wrote just html code. but it is not working

Comment: please check if your single-product.php is in some folder. If yes, then, make that folder in your theme/woocommerce/folder-name

Comment: I would guess that either: a) you're editing the wrong theme, b) you're editing the wrong file or c) the version of woocommerce you are using has different file names.  If you follow the guide I linked to you should be able to resolve things, but without more information we can't help any further.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info mikemike. It might be my theme problem.

Comment: Actually i am converting HTML to wordpress theme. I created all files by following wordpress help blog. Is there any Important code in functions.php file ?